# how to send checkbok state from included JSP page to another JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have three JSP pages. The first one contains a checkbox created using a `for` loop.
Page1.jsp:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="box"+<%=i %> />
%>
```

The second one (Page2.jsp) includes the first one and send the state of the checkbox to the third one (Page2.jsp).

Page2.jsp:

```
 <jsp:include page="Page1.jsp">
 <jsp:param name="type1" value="<%=request.getParameterValues(\"selection\")%>" />
 </jsp:include>
```

Page3.jsp:

```
 <%String valuebd=request.getParameter("type1");
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your first page you create 5 checkboxes with the same name and different values - is this right?. If you include a JSP page you should call it a JSP Fragment (extension .jspf). The code `<jsp:param name="type1"...` reads a request parameter. This is a parameter from a HTTP Request - not from the page. I think, it is easier to solve the problem, if you can tell a little bit more about the things you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would recommend that you don't use scriptlets. They litter code throughout JSP pages and it makes your application extremely difficult to manage. You should use EL (Expression Language). This allows you do add functionality to your JSP page without using Java code, for example:

```
<c:if test="${parameterValue}">
    <p>${parameterValue}</p>
</c:if>
```

Onto your problem. I would recommend passing the value onto the server using a POST request type. From the server, you can then redirect it to the desired JSP page. You shouldn't be thinking about *literally passing* values between your JSP pages. This breaks the paradigm that you're working under when you make web based applications.

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="${parameterValue}"/>
```

By placing something like this element inside a `form` element, and submitting that form, you pass it to your servlet server. Next, in the java code, you can use a `RequestDispatcher` to pass it to the next JSP file.

```
String value = request.getParameter("value");

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This will make the value available in "page2.jsp".